# Observe PropertyChanged on items in an ObservableCollection using System.Reactive

Tags: c#, observablecollection, system.reactive, inotifypropertychanged

I have:

```
public class Vm
{
    private ObservableCollection<Thing> _things;
    public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things
    {
        get { return _things ?? (_things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>()); }
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Thing :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _value) return;
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I want to observe PropertyChanges on all items in the ObservableCollection

Is rx a good fit for this?

How is the observer wired up in this case? (I could post some what-have-you-tried but I don't think it will add much)

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, you may want to look into http://www.reactiveui.net/ which does this and a lot more.

Comment: Will check it out, trying to learn some rx so reinventing would not be a disaster. Going to pull your code and read some.

Comment: I came here to say the same thing as @JimWooley, even if you don't use the library the code is pretty clean and easy to understand as a working example.

Comment: Is rx not a good fit for this?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve and how much coordination of streams you need to do. In some cases simple event handlers are fine. Rx is good for more complex coordinations, although some say all events should be recast as observables which is probably going a bit overboard. FWIW, ReactiveUI is an MVVM framework that uses Rx internally.

Comment: Rxx 2.0 contains [operators](https://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/Rxx/System/Reactive/Linq/Observable2%20-%20PropertyChanges.cs) for this kind of thing.  Use them along with this [conversion operator](https://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/Rxx/System/Reactive/NotifyCollectionChangedExtensions.cs) for `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rx is a perfect fit and I wouldn't call it reinventing the wheel!

Consider this simple extension method for converting property changed events to observable streams:

```
public static class NotifyPropertyChangedExtensions
{
  public static IObservable<PropertyChangedEventArgs> WhenPropertyChanged(this NotifyPropertyChanged notifyPropertyChanged)
  {
      return Observable.FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
        ev => notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged += ev, 
        ev => notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged -= ev);
  }    
}
```

In your view model you simply merge all individual obserable property change stream:

```
public class VM
{
  readonly SerialDisposable subscription;

  public VM()
  {
    subscription = new SerialDisposable();
    Things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
    Things.CollectionChanged += ThingsCollectionChanged;
  }

  void ThingsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    subscription.Disposable = 
      Things.Select(t => t.WhenPropertyChanged())
            .Merge()
            .Subscribe(OnThingPropertyChanged);
  }

  void OnThingPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs obj)
  {
    //ToDo!
  }

  public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things { get; private set; }
}
```