# ListBox binding with ViewModel in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am new to the WPF and trying to build a sample application using the MVVM framework. My application has a xaml file which has some textboxes for inputing customer info, combo box for display of states and a save button. All the databinding is done through ViewModel(CustomerViewMode) which has a reference to the Model(Customer), containing the required fields and their
Getter, setters. The viewModel has a CustomerList property.
On clicking the save button, I want to display the FirstName and LastName properties of Customer in a ListBox. This is where the problem is. I debugged the code,
(Click event of button in the code behind), I can see that the CustomerList has the first Customer object with all its details, but its not getting displayed in the listbox.
My code is:
Customer(Model);

```
enter code here
namespace SampleMVVM.Models
{
class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private String _firstName;
    private String _lastName;
    private Address _customerAddress;


    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _firstName)
            {
                _firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }

    public String LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lastName)
            {
                _lastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
    }

    public Address CustomerAddress
    {
        get { return _customerAddress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _customerAddress)
            {
                _customerAddress = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerAddress");
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


}
```

}

Address(Model)

```
namespace SampleMVVM.Models
{
class Address : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _addressLine1;
    private string _addressLine2;
    private string _city;
    //private string _selectedState;
    private string _postalCode;
    private string _country;






    public String AddressLine1
    {
        get { return _addressLine1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _addressLine1)
            {
                _addressLine1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(AddressLine1);
            }
        }
    }

    public String AddressLine2
    {
        get { return _addressLine2; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _addressLine2)
            {
                _addressLine2 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(AddressLine2);
            }
        }
    }

    public String City
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _city)
            {
                _city = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(City);
            }
        }
    }




    public String PostalCode
    {
        get { return _postalCode; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _postalCode)
            {
                _postalCode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(PostalCode);
            }
        }
    }

    public String Country
    {
        get { return _country; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _country)
            {
                _country = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(Country);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

}

CustomerViewModel:

```
namespace SampleMVVM.ViewModels
{
class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Customer _customer;
    RelayCommand _saveCommand;
    private List<String> _stateList = new List<string>();
    private string _selectedState;

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();


    //public CustomerViewModel(ObservableCollection<Customer> customers)
    //{
    //    _customers = new ListCollectionView(customers);

    //}



    public Customer CustomerModel
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _customer)
            {
                _customer = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerModel");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> StateList
    {
        get
        {

            return _stateList;
        }
        set { _stateList = value; }

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList
    {
        get
        {

            return _customerList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _customerList)
            {
                _customerList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerList");
            }

        }

    }


    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        CustomerModel = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Fred",
            LastName = "Anders",

            CustomerAddress = new Address
            {
                AddressLine1 = "Northeastern University",
                AddressLine2 = "360, Huntington Avenue",
                City = "Boston",
                PostalCode = "02115",
                Country = "US",


            }
        };

        StateList = new List<String>
        {
            "Alaska", "Arizona", "California", "Connecticut", "Massachusetts", "New Jersey", "Pennsylvania", "Texas"
        };
        SelectedState = StateList.FirstOrDefault();


    }

    public String SelectedState
    {
        get { return _selectedState; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedState)
            {
                _selectedState = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedState);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

        }
```

}

CustomerInfo.xaml(view)

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleMVVM.Views.CustomerInfo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:SampleMVVM.ViewModels"             
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:CustomerViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>



<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <!--Starting label-->
    <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" 
               Foreground="Navy" 
               Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            Customer Information:
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Text="First name: " Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="1" Width="80px" Height="50px" Margin="40,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerModel.FirstName}" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0"  Name="fname"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Last Name: " Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="2" Width="80px" Height="50px" Margin="40,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerModel.LastName}" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0" Name="lname"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Address: " Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="3" Width="80px" Height="50px" Margin="40,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerModel.CustomerAddress.AddressLine1}" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="160px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerModel.CustomerAddress.AddressLine2}" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="160px" Height="30px" Margin="20,5,0,0"/>

    <TextBlock Text="City: " Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="5" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="40,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerModel.CustomerAddress.City}" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0"/>

    <TextBlock Text="State: " Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="6" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="40,5,0,0"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listOfSates"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StateList}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedState}"
              SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
              >


    </ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Text="PostalCode: " Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="7" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="40,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerModel.CustomerAddress.PostalCode}"  Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Country: " Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Grid.Row="8" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="40,5,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerModel.CustomerAddress.Country}" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Width="80px" Height="20px" Margin="20,5,0,0"/>

    <Button Content="Save" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Grid.Row="9"  Width="50px" Height="20px" Name="savebtn" Margin="40,5,0,0"
             Click="savebtn_Click"/>


    <ListBox Name="cList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomerList}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="200px" Height="300px" Margin="200,5,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerModel.FirstName}"
                           FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Navy"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=", " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerModel.LastName}"
                           FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Navy"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

CustomerInfo(Code behind class)

```
namespace SampleMVVM.Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CustomerInfo.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CustomerInfo : UserControl
{
    public CustomerInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //checkvalue();
    }

            private void savebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ////Customer c = new Customer();
        ////c.FirstName = fname.Text;
        ////c.LastName = lname.Text;
        //CustomerViewModel cvm = new CustomerViewModel();
        //cvm.CustomerModel.FirstName = fname.Text;
        //cvm.CustomerModel.LastName = lname.Text;
        //List<CustomerViewModel> customerList = new List<CustomerViewModel>();
        //customerList.Add(cvm);
        var viewModel = DataContext as CustomerViewModel;


        if (viewModel != null)
        {

            //viewModel.ShowCustomerInfo();
            String strfname = viewModel.CustomerModel.FirstName;
            String strname = viewModel.CustomerModel.LastName;

            viewModel.CustomerList.Add(viewModel.CustomerModel);
            String str1 = viewModel.CustomerList.FirstOrDefault().FirstName;
            int i = viewModel.CustomerList.Count();
            //cList.ItemsSource = viewModel.CustomerList;

        }

    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerViewModel cvm = new CustomerViewModel();
        cvm.SelectedState = listOfSates.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }




}
```

}

I just cant understand where am I going wrong...Someone please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And for the correct binding in `ListBox.ItemTemplate`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"
           FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Navy"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"
           FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Navy"/>
```

The `DataContext` of `ListBoxItem` is a Customer already.

Comment: Thank you so much :)...i changed the bindings inside the listbox and it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

You only create a new instance of a CustomerModel object once in your code (in the Customer View Model constructor). So you are constantly updating the same customer object rather than creating a new one.

At the end of your click handler you should do a

```
viewModel.CustomerModel = new Customer();
```

**HOWEVER**

Rather than having a click handler you should have an ICommand in your view model for adding a new customer. Then you should bind to command of your button to the ICommand in your view model.

Comment: Agree, but should be `viewModel.CustomerModel = new Customer();`

Answer (score 3):

you were binding the CustomerLIst.FirstName which is not walid because innterconent will check for property name customerlist in side the listbox itemssource. and as its not their then it will raise a silent error but wo't show into GUI, what you need to do is just provide the propertyname like firstname and lastname that will work.

well besides your binding in listbox every thing else is ok. just replace you listbox binding as like below.

```
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="List of Customers" />
        <ListBox Name="cList"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.RowSpan="8"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="10"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding CustomerList.Count,
                                  StringFormat='Total Customers, ={0}'}" />
```

better to take command insteed of events.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line of code:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerList");
```

It doesn't work for collection add/remove events. Take a look at [ObservableCollection and Item PropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901921/observablecollection-and-item-propertychanged).

Keep in mind that in MVVM, you should not have much code (if any) in code behind. Consider using commands.