# List box change between ItemTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have `ListBox` in my `Application` that i design with `ItemTemplateSelector`:

```
TemplateSelector templateSelector = new TemplateSelector();

templateSelector.SongTemplate = Resources["Template"] as DataTemplate;
templateSelector.SongTemplateCached = Resources["TemplateCached"] as DataTemplate;

HistoryList.ItemTemplateSelector = templateSelector;
```

And the different between them is that if the song was download or not download.

This is the ViewModel for the listbox :

```
    ObservableCollection<SongItem> songlist;

    public const int MAX_RECENT = 10000;

    public HistoryViewModel()
    {
        NotificationCenterManager.Instance.AddObserver(UpdateCache, AppConst.UPDATECACH);

        List<SongItem> tmpArr = SqlLiteManager.CreateInstance().LoadHistoryFromDatabase();

        songList = new ObservableCollection<SongItem>(tmpArr);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SongItem> SongList
    {
        get { return songlist; }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void UpdateCache(Notification p_notification)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("SomeName");
    }
```

And when the song finish download the `UpdateCache` method is called but the ListBox won't update(change the design from the SongTemplate mode to SongTemplateCached)

How i can fix it?

## Edit

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VideoList}" Name="HistoryList" Style="{StaticResource myListboxStyle}" BorderThickness="0" 
             Template="{DynamicResource ListViewNewTemplate}" Margin="-2,0,0,0" MouseDoubleClick="Mouse_Double_Click" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">

        <ListBox.Resources>

            <!--Defines a context menu-->
            <ContextMenu x:Key="MyElementMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Delete from history" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>

            <!--Sets a context menu for each ListBoxItem in the current ListBox-->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyElementMenu}"/>
            </Style>

        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

Selector:

```
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string filePath = ApplicationDataPaths.GetRootDataPath() + "\\www\\CachedContent\\";

            string file = video.VideoId + "*.mp4";

            string[] listfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(filePath, file, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (listfiles.Length > 0)
            {
                return VideoTemplateCached;
            }
            else
            {
                return VideoTemplate;
            }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the related xaml and the selector?

Comment: @Herm I edit the post for you.

Comment: from where are you getting "video" in your SelectTemplate method?

Comment: Video and Song is the same thing

Comment: so you already have SongItem in the collection and you just update its property on download complete and then you want to change its template using selector?

Comment: Yep. i want to change the template selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the property of the Song-Item, but you've got a Binding to the Collection containing the Song-Item. It will not be notified to update the UI, unless you raise a `CollectionChangedEvent` when an item is changed.

I guess you have to implement a notification like [ObservableCollection and Item PropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901921/observablecollection-and-item-propertychanged) to be able to update the UI.

Comment: But i don't change the Array. I just need to refresh the ListView layout

Comment: that's the problem. Because you don't change the array, your Binding does not know that it has to refresh.

Comment: perhaps you should take a look at another approach, like http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4fd42590-8375-46d0-b7bc-6c217df0f0ba/switch-items-datatemplate?forum=wpf - then you do not need a selector because you could solve this one with a datatrigger (bound to the correct property)