# Update list values after update root class object

Tags: c#, list, linq, oop

I have the following classes:

```
public class Class_A
{
    public string my_field { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; } 
    // etc...
}

public class Class_B
{
    public string my_field { get; set; }
    public Class_A field_A { get; set; } 
    // etc...
}

public class Class_C
{
    public string my_field { get; set; }
    public Class_A field_A { get; set; } 
    // etc...
}

List<Class_A> list_A = new List<Class_A>(); //and then populate it
List<Class_B> list_B = new List<Class_B>(); //and then populate it
List<Class_C> list_C = new List<Class_C>(); //and then populate it
```

And then, when I update some element of `list_A`, for example

```
Class_A old_a, new_a;
old_a = list_A.Where("some condition").FirstOrDefault();
new_a = new Class_A();//and then initialize it
list_A[list_A.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(old_a))] = new_a;
```

I need, that all elements of `list_B` and `list_C`, which field `Class_A` equals `old_a` will be update to `new_a`.

**1. What is the best way to do this? Now I have following variant, but I think, that it's could be better:**

```
list_B.Where(x => x.Class_A.Equals(old_a)).ForEach(x => x.Class_A = new_a);
```

**2. What is the best way to update all values, if I'll have this code?**

```
public class Class_D
{
    public string my_field { get; set; }
    public List<Class_A> list_A { get; set; } 
    // etc...
}

List<Class_D> list_D = new List<Class_D>(); //and then populate it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ObservableCollection and Item PropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901921/observablecollection-and-item-propertychanged)

You can make from your list_A an observable collection when can be received by Class_B and Class_C.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. I'll try to use it.