# Why does this Binding not work, when the property is referenced in a ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding

I have the following problem, which I cannot comprehend. I'm quite new to Xamarin, and I've been working on this particular problem for quite some time now.

**TL;DR:** I have an MyGroups[] array, which is used by a Repeater in XAML. The DataTemplate, used by the Repeater, has an ObservableCollection, which *is populated in XAML*. Binding one of MyGroups's properties with Description.Title does not work, however using the same property outside of the Description Collection works just fine.

Long story:

Let's say we have a Repeater, which is populated by the VM's MyGroups[] property. The Repeater and Models:Group look something like this:

```
<Grial:Repeater ItemTemplate = "{ DynamicResource GroupDataTemplate }"
                           ItemsSource  = "{ Binding MyGroups }"/>
```

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
   public class Group
   {
      public string MyProperty
      {
         get;
         set;
      }

      public string MyOtherProperty
      {
         get;
         set;
      }
   }
}
```

This Repeater gets the following DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key = "GroupDataTemplate">
   <Cards:CardTemplate x:DataType = "Models:Group">

      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions = "Center"
                   VerticalOptions   = "Center">
         <Label>
            <Label.Text>
               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0} {1}">     //<---- this works
                  <Binding Path = "MyProperty" />
                  <Binding Source = "{ x:Static Strings:AppResources.MyString }"/>
               </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Text
         </Label>
      </StackLayout>


      <Cards:CardTemplate.Descriptions>
         <Models:Description>
            <Models:Description.Title>
               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0} {1}">     //<---- this value is always null
                  <Binding Path = "MyProperty" />
                  <Binding Source = "{ x:Static Strings:AppResources.MyString }"/>
               </MultiBinding>
            </Models:Description.Title>
         </Models:Description>


         <Models:Description>
            <Models:Description.Title>
               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0} {1}">     //<---- this value is always null
                  <Binding Path = "MyOtherProperty" />
                  <Binding Source = "{ x:Static Strings:AppResources.MyString }"/>
               </MultiBinding>
            </Models:Description.Title>
         </Models:Description>

      </Cards:CardTemplate.Descriptions>
   </Cards:CardTemplate>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Cards:CardTemplate looks something like this:

```
<Grial:CardView ...>

   ...

   <Grial:GridView RowSpacing  = "16"
                   Grid.Row    = "1"
                   ColumnCount = "2"
                   ItemsSource = "{ Binding Source={ RelativeSource AncestorType={ x:Type Cards:CardTemplate } }, Path=Descriptions }">

      <Grial:GridView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Name = "x_cardItemsDescriptionTemplate">
            <StackLayout Spacing     = "5"
                         Orientation = "Horizontal">

               <Label VerticalOptions = "Center"
                      Text            = "{ Binding Source={ RelativeSource AncestorType={ x:Type Models:Description } }, Path=Icon }"/>

               <Label VerticalOptions = "Center"
                      Text            = "{ Binding Source={ RelativeSource AncestorType={ x:Type Models:Description } }, Path=Description }"/>
            </StackLayout>
         </DataTemplate>
      </Grial:GridView.ItemTemplate>
   </Grial:GridView>
</Grial:CardView>
```

The Description looks like this

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;


public class Description
   : BindableObject
{
   public static readonly BindableProperty IconProperty = BindableProperty.Create( propertyName: nameof( Description.Icon ),
                                                                                   returnType: typeof( string ),
                                                                                   declaringType: typeof( Description ),
                                                                                   defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                                                   propertyChanged: Description.OnIconChanged );

   public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create( propertyName: nameof( Description.Title ),
                                                                                    returnType: typeof( string ),
                                                                                    declaringType: typeof( Description ),
                                                                                    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                                                    propertyChanged: Description.OnTitleChanged );

   public string Icon
   {
      get => (string)GetValue( IconProperty );
      set => SetValue( property: IconProperty, value: value );
   }

   public string Title
   {
      get => (string)GetValue( TitleProperty );
      set => SetValue( property: TitleProperty, value: value );
   }


   private static void OnIconChanged( BindableObject bindable, object old_value, object new_value )
   {
      try
      {
         ( (Description)bindable ).Icon = new_value as string;
      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
         ...
      }
   }

   private static void OnTitleChanged( BindableObject bindable, object old_value, object new_value )
   {
      try
      {
         ( (Description)bindable ).Title = new_value as string;
      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

What I don't understand is why {Binding Path=MyProperty} works for the Label, but not for the Description. The problem is not the CardTemplate, because every hard-coded or resource-bound string gets assigned to the appropriate element. The only problem is the binding itself!

Things I've tried:

- BindingList instead of ObservableCollections
- Description inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged/BindableObject
- Assigning "Source={ RelativeSource AncestorType={ x:Type Models:Group } }" with or without levels
- {Binding .MyProperty}, {Binding Models:Groups.MyProperty}, {Binding /MyProperty}
- Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in Group

Nothing seems to work, and I cannot understand why? Why does the Label.Text has its value set correctly, but Description.Title not. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: There may be a binding error. Please look at the output to search for anything suspicious.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output is clear. I've compiled for iOS and Android, with `[ assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlCompilation( Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlCompilationOptions.Compile ) ]`, and with `Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Log.Listeners.Add(new DelegateLogListener((arg1, arg2) => Debug.WriteLine(arg2)));` without any success.

Comment: Have you check the property get the correct value? What is you viewmodel? Could you a completed code sanippet for me to reproduce?

Comment: The property does contain the correct value, as demostrated by the `Label`.

[Here](https://github.com/pgiokoglou/BlankApp1) is a demo that reproduces the problem...

Comment: I downloaded the sample, but i could not open it in VS. Could you check it again?

Comment: I just downloaded directly from github, and I was able to open and compile it

Comment: I checked the code again. Maybe there is something wrong with my VS. Now, i could open it. Could you give more details about how to reproduce? Where you used `Binding Path= Description` for?

Comment: In MainPage.xaml there is an assignment `<Models:CardDescription Text="{Binding Path=ItemsQuantity}"/>` (l: 32) which is the problem. Same assignment in the label above (commented out) works just fine.

Further experimentation showed me that the `PropertyChanged` event is not getting triggered for the elements in the array. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3478581/9071302). This is the part that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution/workaround to my problem. It's not 100% how I wanted it, but, meh, close enough I guess.

What I couldn't achieve is to use MultiBindings, but I don't strictly need to concatenate multiple strings in my use case, so I settled for a StringFormat.

```
<Cards:CardTemplate x:Name = "template">
    <Cards:CardTemplate.Descriptions>
        <Models:Description Title = "{ Binding Path=BindingContext.MyProperty, Source={ x:Reference Name=template }, StringFormat=... }"/>
    </Cards:CardTemplate.Descriptions>
</Cards:CardTemplate>
```

The two important points are the `BindingContext.` of the `Path=BindingContext.MyProperty` and the `Source` referencing the container View. Since the `MyProperty` is only available on the level of the `CardTemplate`, all children of the `CardTemplate` have no idea of its existence. To make if available to them, we use the `Source` property to reference the template, and then use `BindingContext` to reference the current object of the ViewModel's container (in this case `MyGroup`). Since we now have access to each `MyGroup` object, we can call its properties (in this case `MyProperty`), thus reaching our goal.

Why this does not work with `MultiBinding` is beyond me, but it's more than enough rn.