# how to use NotifyPropertyChange master from detail values in Master-Detail

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, master-detail

I have a master-detail relationship in some custom entities. Say I have the following structure:

```
    class Master : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // + property changed implementation 
    public string Name { get; set; } // + property changed implementation

    public ObservableCollection<Detail> Details { get; }
    public long sumValue{get{return Details.Sum(x=>x.value -x.discount );}}
}

class Detail : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public int Id { get; private set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public double Discont{ get; set; } // + property changed implementation
     public double Value { get; set; } // + property changed implementation
}
```

if i change row 5 in detail discount Or value How can refresh sumValue?
[image: property change dose not worked]

i add row 1 and set amount 1  and row sum row is 2000

and add new row 2 set amount 5 and row sum is 10000

but sum in master frezz on last row 2000!

if i call

```
    NotifyPropertyChange("sumValue");
```

from master ui updated sumvalue Property!

how can i use

```
        NotifyPropertyChange("sumValue");
```

from master Property in Detail Property

like this:

```
 public double Discont{ get{ return _discount } set{_discount = value; NotifyPropertyChange("sumValue");} }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ObservableCollection and Item PropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901921/observablecollection-and-item-propertychanged)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen on the `CollectionChanged` of your `Details` and on any `PropertyChanged` event of the details in the list.
The `CollectionChanged` event will tell you when objects are added, removed, moved or replaced in the list. But the `ObservableCollection` does not listen on `PropertyChanged` events on its content, so you need to do it on your own.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3478581/6560579) answer as a reference how you can do that

Comment: Ty I Fix it                    _commodityModelList.CollectionChanged += _commodityModelList_CollectionChanged;