# Making animations run smoother

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

My WPF program's storyboard animations stutter ruining user experience (for example on adding larger number of items to ObservableCollection and ListBox being updated).

My idea was to make animation run smoother by dispatching them with higher priority so I tried

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
 //all animations
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()  =>
    { sb.Begin(); 

    }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send);
```

I thought there would be difference between "Send" as highest priority and "SystemIdle" as lowest, but there isn't.

I hope there is small problem in my understanding of the dispatcher and there is a simple fix, but I am open to any ideas of improving animation performance.

**EDIT**

1. Implemented on each animated control RenderTargetBitmap which takes screenshot on animation start and replaces complicated visual tree with one image control, and switches it back when animation is complete
2. Populating listbox that ruins my animation in Dispatcher with SystemIdle priority
3. Set framerate to 30
4. Checked in perfmon and nothing seems software rendered, RenderTier is 2

If I disable populating listbox completely everything runs smoothly

Listbox is populated like this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  List<MyData> _f = new List<MyData>();
  //populate _f
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    _MyCollection.Clear();
    _MyCollection.AddRange(_f); //Adding items without raising events *
  }), DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle);
}
```

*I even use addRange for ObservableCollection from [ObservableCollection : calling OnCollectionChanged with multiple new items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300845/observablecollection-calling-oncollectionchanged-with-multiple-new-items)

Comment: There's no easy way to improve performance. Dispatcher priority is about when animation will start, not about what priority animating each frame will have (it's hardcoded I think). If animated items aren't changed and just move, you can try bitmap caching. Besides that, the only way to improve performance is to simplify items. AFAIK.

Comment: try [this](http://wpftutorial.net/FrameRate.html). Also, make sure everything is being hardware-accelerated. there are tools for that.

Comment: @Athari I had high hopes for bitmap caching, but there was no difference.

Comment: @HighCore I already had it set to 30. For 300ms quick transition I get only 2 frames in-between.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow RenderTargetBitmap of the whole grid, do the animations and transitions and then replace bitmap with original control?

Comment: I implemented on each animated control RenderTargetBitmap which takes screenshot on animation start and replaces complicated visual tree with one image control, and switches it back when animation is complete, but there was no difference in performance.