# what is notifycollectionchangedaction reset value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, reset, inotifycollectionchanged

I have an observable collection...`SelectableDataContext<T>`..And in the generic class `SelectableDataContext<T>` is...having two private member variables

1. Private T item.
2. Private bool isSelected.

When the IsSelected property changes...My collection's changed property is not firing .

I think it should fire...because it's `Reset` in `INotifyCollectionChangedAction`.

Answer (score 46):

This is an old question but for the benefit of anyone who may come across this through a search as I did:

`NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` means "The content of the collection changed dramatically".  One case where the Reset event is raised is when you call `Clear()` on the underlying observable collection.

With the Reset event, you don't get the `NewItems` and `OldItems` collections in the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` parameter.

This means you're better off using the "sender" of the event to get a reference to the modified collection and use that directly, i.e. assume it's a new list.

An example of this might be something like:

```cs
((INotifyCollectionChanged)stringCollection).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(StringCollection_CollectionChanged);
  ...

void StringCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (string s in e.NewItems)
            {
                InternalAdd(s);
            }
            break;

        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            foreach (string s in e.OldItems)
            {
                InternalRemove(s);
            }
            break;

        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> col = sender as ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>;
            InternalClearAll();
            if (col != null)
            {
                foreach (string s in col)
                {
                    InternalAdd(s);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Lots of discussions on this Reset event here: [When Clearing an ObservableCollection, There are No Items in e.OldItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224155/when-clearing-an-observablecollection-there-are-no-items-in-e-olditems).

Comment: MS changed the definition of Reset. It now means: "The content of the collection was cleared." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Not anymore. It has been clarified as "changed dramatically", which could mean cleared, but also every element changed. See https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/3253

Comment: Which means if you're using it to add/remove PropertyChanged handlers in the items themselves, you need to maintain a second list in the background just so you have an OldItems when Reset comes along. Not a big deal if you're just using ObservableCollection and never call Clear, but definitely something you need to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

When a value of a propery in an object changes, it should notify others using `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation.

On the other hand, when `number of items` or `items themselves` change in a collection, it should let others know using `INotifyCollectionChanged` implementation.

Now, in your case, value of a property of an object in your collection changes. That is supposed to raise `PropertyChanged` event, not `CollectionChanged` event.

Answer (score -1):

Collection changed will be fired if and only if you modify the collection that is via either Adding a new Item or Removing an existing item from the collection.