# MVVM Listbox in tab control is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I'm struggling with update issue. I have tab control with the listbox binded to an Observable Collection

```
ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"
     x:Name="LbxMenu" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding TestListsNames}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight" FontSize="18"/>
```

view model:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _testListsName;

    public ObservableCollection<string> TestListsNames
    {
        get { return _testListsName; }
        set{ _testListsName = value; }
   }
```

After inserting entity to database there is an event which invokes TestListInitialize method in my ViewModel which should refresh collection and it works as I can see it in debugger. But listbox doesn't refresh and I have to restart application to see changes. 
It worked great when it was in separate window but when I changed ui to tab control it doesn't.

Update function:

```
private void TestListNamesInitialize()
    {
        TestListsNames = db.GetTestListNamesFromDatabase();
        if (TestListsNames.Count != 0) CanLoad = true;           

    }
```

Initial Window:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Test.View.InitialWindow"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:tabdata="clr-namespace:Test.View.TabItems"

    Title="Testownik" Height="600" Width="900" ShowTitleBar="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" Icon="../GraphicResources/Icon.ico">


<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Content="settings" />
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="about" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
<Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl x:Name ="MainTabControl">
    <TabItem Header="Learn" Width="280">
        <tabdata:LearnTabItem/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Database" Width="280">
        <tabdata:DatabaseTabItem/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Statistics" Width="299">
        <tabdata:StatisticsTabItem/>
    </TabItem>
</Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
```

Code behind:

```
    public partial class InitialWindow : MetroWindow
{
    InitialWindowViewModel viewModel=new InitialWindowViewModel();
    public InitialWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

}

DatabaseTabItem:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.View.TabItems.DatabaseTabItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         xmlns:tabData="clr-namespace:Test.View.TabItems"
         Height="500" Width="900" Background="White" BorderBrush="Transparent">
<UserControl.Resources>


</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>

    <Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl x:Name ="DatabaseTabControl" Grid.Column="0" TabStripPlacement="Left" >
        <TabItem Header="Choose" Width="250" >
            <tabData:ChooseFromDbTabItem/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Add" Width="250">
            <tabData:AddToDbTabItem/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Remove" Width="250">
            <tabData:DeleteFromDbTabItem/>
        </TabItem>
    </Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
    DatabaseViewModel vm = new DatabaseViewModel();
    public DatabaseTabItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm;
    }

}
```

ChooseFromDbTabItem:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.View.TabItems.ChooseFromDbTabItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.View.TabItems"
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="650" Background="White" BorderBrush="Transparent">

<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"
     x:Name="LbxMenu" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding TestListsNames}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight" FontSize="18"/>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
  public partial class ChooseFromDbTabItem : UserControl
{
    public ChooseFromDbTabItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you updating the list? Can you provide that code? That is, the TestListInitialize method. I suspect that you are using the property setter, which does NOT raise any PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Database: 
`public void ImportToDatabase(string testName)
        {
            _testName = testName;
            DocumentProcessor processor = new DocumentProcessor();
            processor.ProcessDocFile();
            OnDatabaseUpdated(new EventArgs());
        }`       

ViewModel:
contructor: 

`public DatabaseViewModel()
        {
            db = new DatabaseOperations();
  .....
     db.DatabaseUpdated += (sender, args) => TestListNamesInitialize();
 }

`

Comment: please update your question with that code. It is hard to read code in the comment section.

Comment: function: 

`private void TestListNamesInitialize()
        {
            TestListsNames = db.GetTestListNamesFromDatabase();
            if (TestListsNames.Count != 0) CanLoad = true;           

        }

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rise `PropertyChanged` event for the reason you change your **entire** collection and not a single item (if you changed a single item that was updated through the Observable).

```
 private ObservableCollection<string> _testListsName;
    public ObservableCollection<string> TestListsNames
    {
        get { return _testListsName; }
        set
        {
            if (_testListsName != value)
            {
                _testListsName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TestListsNames");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I thought the ObservableCollection rises it automatically

Comment: The ObservableCollection  rise if something within the list change (Add, Remove, Replace...), but if we change the list (New) we need to rise property changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are not raising the PropertyChanged event when replacing the list using the property setter. Generelly, try to make collection properties readonly to reduce the risk for these sort of errors. Instead, clear the list and repopulate it. This will make sure that the view is notified about any changes.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _testListsName;

    public ObservableCollection<string> TestListsNames
    {
        get { return _testListsName; }
    }

    private void TestListNamesInitialize()
    {
        _testListsName.Clear();
        foreach(string name in db.GetTestListNamesFromDatabase())
        {
            _testListsName.Add(name);
        }

        if (_testListsNames.Count != 0) CanLoad = true;
    }
}
```

However, note that this will raise changed events on each item using the .Add() call. See here: [Can I somehow temporarily disable WPF data binding changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572522/can-i-somehow-temporarily-disable-wpf-data-binding-changes)

Edit: from your updated code. It can also be seen that you do not set the DataContext on your ChooseFromDbTabItem. You need to bind the DataContext property to the view model that exposes the collection:

```
<TabItem Header="Choose" Width="250" >
    <tabData:ChooseFromDbTabItem DataContext="{Binding}" />
</TabItem>
```

Comment: @derp - Where are you initializing the list for the first time?

Comment: In the constructor of the viewmodel

Comment: @derp Can you check in the debugger what is returned from db.GetTestListNamesFromDatabase() ? Because this solution most definitely works for me.

Comment: As previous I get list with all inserted content but unfortunately the listbox in tabitem is not refreshing

Comment: Ok. Then I would need to see some more code. Sounds like there is a DataContext problem.

Comment: Try to check your output & see if you have binding errors

Comment: @derb - I can't see where you are binding to the collection in the code you posted?

Comment: @derb - There is your problem. You are not setting the DataContext on the ChooseFromDbTabItem. See my updated answer. Which 'ViewModel' class is exposing the TestListsName collection?

Comment: @lenkan Thanks for your help. The problem was as Hodaya Shalom noticed I didn't raise OnPropertyChange in Observable Collection

Comment: @derb - Yes, I know. I mentioned this in the first line of my answer. I was just trying to make you follow .NET programming guidelines. I.e., do not provide settable collection properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx . But this is a minor issue in view model classes, so whatever floats your boat =).