# Suspend updates to ObservableCollection<T> in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Rather new to WPF and XAML. There is a grid item in the XAML which has dynamic binding to properties on the VM:

```
(.xaml file)
\\...
ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsGridItems}"
SelectedIndex="{Binding DetailsGridSelectedIndex}"
\\...
```

Is it possible to temporarily suspend (or "unbind") updates to the grid item which is bound to my `ObservableCollection<T>` member (DetailsGridItems)? Then, when ready manually update (or "rebind") the grid item?

Basically, I'd like to make a number of changes to "DetailsGridItems" and be able to control when GUI updates occur, in a similar manner to `System.Windows.Forms.ListView.BeginUpdate` and `ListView.EndUpdate`.

#### Update

The answer in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572522), specifically the subclass approach using `ObservableCollectionEx` given by @XiaoguoGe, works nicely.

Comment: Seems to me if you want to do this, you're using the wrong collection type. Just use a `List<T>`, and replace the entire collection reference when you want the UI updated. But if you really want to use `ObservableCollection<T>` see duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I used the `ObservableCollectionEx` subclass approach given in that other question, which gives me exactly what I need. Thanks for pointing out the duplicate.