# RibbonComboBox changes its DataContext to {DisconnectedItem}

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am developing a WPF project and am experimenting a very strange behaviour.

I have added a `RibbonComboBox` to the Ribbon and inside of it there is a `RibbonGallery` which has a `RibbonGalleryCategory` that has a binding to an array of elements.

```
<rb:RibbonComboBox Name="xComboBox" Label="List:" >
       <rb:RibbonGallery SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
              <rb:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding List}" />
       </rb:RibbonGallery>
</rb:RibbonComboBox>
```

Everything works just fine so far, when I run the program the RibbonComboBox has its items as expected.

The problem starts when I resize the container window to a very small size, after doing that and resizing it back, the ComboBox is **empty**!!

I have no idea why this is happening, am I doing something wrong??

I have tried to see what is going on, so, I added an event to the `Items` property of the `RibbonGalleryCategory` as follow:

```
public RibbonView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RibbonGallery gallery = xComboBox.Items[0] as RibbonGallery;

        RibbonGalleryCategory galleryCat = gallery .Items[0] as RibbonGalleryCategory;

        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)galleryCat.Items).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(RibbonView_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void RibbonView_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                switch (e.Action)
                {
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                        MessageBox.Show("Collection has changed >>>> Add");
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                        MessageBox.Show("Collection has changed >>>> Move");
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                        MessageBox.Show("Collection has changed >>>> Remove");
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                        MessageBox.Show("Collection has changed >>>> Replace");
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                        MessageBox.Show("Collection has changed >>>> Reset");
                        break;
                }
            }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
    }
```

As you can see, I show what is the change in the collection, so, after running the program and resizing the window, my little test tells me that the collection was "**reset**"!!

Does anyone know why this happens?? How can I prevent the RibbonComboBox from losing its data??

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

More info: I just noticed something, after resizing the container window the RibbonComboBox changes its DataContext for an object called "**`{DisconnectedItem}`**". I have done some research and found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/36aec363-9e33-45bd-81f0-1325a735cc45/#611fccf2-737f-4309-a793-4001488b23aa). But I still dont know how to prevent from it.

Does anybody know how to avoid that a control loses its DataContext (which makes the combobox lose its data)?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction(v=vs.95).aspx) doesn't have much to offer but see Orion Edwards answer towards the bottom of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224155/when-clearing-an-observablecollection-there-are-no-items-in-e-olditems) link.

**Basically "something dramatic has happened!"**

Maybe rebuilding the list from scratch, as he suggests, upon re-size will be the trick.